# Google apps with Latitude

Tags: google-workspace, google-latitude

I use google apps for my domain, my apps account has all my mail and contacts so when i got my android phone i logged into my apps account on it and it works fine, even serivces that i can't login into normally work, like maps and latitude.

My problem is now that although yes latitiude works fine i cant actually login and manage it, location tracking is what im looking for so i can record journeys for mileage expenses.

Has anyone come across a way to use latitude properly with apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google now let you optionaly transfer google apps accounts to normal accounts, works fine

Comment: Can you provide the link?

Comment: Without a link this doesn't really help future users.